# what is meaning of $# in perl?

Tags: perl

Consider the following code:

```
my @candidates = get_candidates($marker);
CANDIDATE:
for my $i (0..$#candidates) {
  next CANDIDATE if open_region($i);
  $candidates[$i] = $incumbent{ $candidates[$i]{region} };
}
```

What is meaning `$#` in line 3?

Comment: u should have gone through basic before commenting / putting question here.

Comment: @dev kumar:  BTW, `$#arrayname` can also be used on the left-side of an assignment to change the highest index number, to extend or truncate an array (not often used).

Comment: `$#` is documented in `man perlvar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since candidates is an array, `$#candidates` is the largest index (number of elements - 1)

For example:

```
my @x = (4,5,6); 
print $#x;
```

will print `2` since that is the largest index.

Note that if the array is empty, `$#candidates` will be -1

EDIT: from `perldoc perlvar`:

```
           $# is also used as sigil, which, when prepended on the name of
           an array, gives the index of the last element in that array.

               my @array        = ("a", "b", "c");
               my $last_index   = $#array;   # $last_index is 2

               for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
                   print "The value of index $i is $array[$i]\n";
               }
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a value of last index on array (in your case it is last index on candidates).

Answer (score 4):

This means `array_size - 1`. It is the same as `(scalar @array) - 1`.

Comment: It holds true even if the array is empty (and gives you -1)

Comment: Although the value might be the same as `(scalar @array) - 1` it is not a shortcut to it.  The highest index and the number of elements are held as separate values in the array metadata.

Comment: While it rarely happens, `$[` can be set to a value other than 0, in which case the relationship between the value of `$#` and the number of elements in the array changes.

Answer (score 2):

In perl ,we have several ways to get an array size ,such as print @arr,print scalar (@arr) ,print $#arr+1  and so on.No reason ,just use it.You will get familiar with some default usage in perl during your further contact with perl .Unlike C++/java ,perl use a lot of
special expression to simplify our coding , but sometimes it always make us more confused.